# Why is "\b" not clearing one character at left?

Tags: c

I'm trying to print 01-99 in words and I am somewhat successful.

Here is the source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char a, b;
    char *digit1;
    char *digit2;

    // get digit character by character
    scanf("%c%c", &a, &b);

    switch(a) {
        case '1':
            switch(b) {
                case '0':
                    digit1 = "ten";
                    break;

                case '1':
                    digit1 = "eleven";
                    break;

                case '2':
                    digit1 = "twelve";
                    break;

                case '3':
                    digit1 = "thirteen";
                    break;

                case '4':
                    digit1 = "fourteen";
                    break;

                case '5':
                    digit1 = "fifteen";
                    break;

                case '6':
                    digit1 = "sixteen";
                    break;

                case '7':
                    digit1 = "seventeen";
                    break;

                case '8':
                    digit1 = "eighteen";
                    break;

                case '9':
                    digit1 = "nineteen";
                    break;

                default:
                    digit1 = "";
                    break;
            }
            break;

        case '2':
            digit1 = "twenty-";
            break;

        case '3':
            digit1 = "thirty-";
            break;

        case '4':
            digit1 = "forty-";
            break;

        case '5':
            digit1 = "fifty-";
            break;

        case '6':
            digit1 = "sixty-";
            break;

        case '7':
            digit1 = "seventy-";
            break;

        case '8':
            digit1 = "eighty-";
            break;

        case '9':
            digit1 = "ninty-";
            break;

        default:
            digit1 = "";
    }

    switch(b) {
        case '1':
            digit2 = "one";
            break;

        case '2':
            digit2 = "two";
            break;

        case '3':
            digit2 = "three";
            break;

        case '4':
            digit2 = "four";
            break;

        case '5':
            digit2 = "five";
            break;

        case '6':
            digit2 = "six";
            break;

        case '7':
            digit2 = "seven";
            break;

        case '8':
            digit2 = "eight";
            break;

        case '9':
            digit2 = "nine";
            break;

        case '0':
            digit2 = "\b";
            break;

        default:
            digit2 = strcpy(digit1, "\b");
    }

    if (a != 1) {
        printf("%s%s\n", digit1, digit2);
    }
    else {
        printf("%s\n", digit1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm successful in printing from 20-99 until now. But there is an error. If I enter any of 20, 30, 40... `-` is not removed as it should be cause I used `\b` to remove that.

Comment: `\b` doesn't really mean what you think it means. You need to not print the `-` out unless you need it, instead of trying to erase it after already printing it out.

Comment: @jxh `\b` == BACKSPACE == "clear one character left". Am I wrong?

Comment: Where does the C standard say it has to "clear one character left"? Anyway, if you send the output to a file instead of the screen, the `\b` would actually show up in the file itself. Any attempt you are making to fix your output with control sequences only affects its appearance on the screen, which is not the same as emitting correct output.

Comment: `\b` means to backspace a character. Technically it doesn't clear the character unless you overwrite it with something else. If you're running Linux, try this at the prompt and see what you get: `echo -e "abc\b\b1". If `\b` were "erase" then you'd get `a1`. But instead you get `a1c`. It just moves the cursor back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little outside of the C standard as it concerns the behavior of the input/output environment, but usually the backspace character just repositions the cursor. To back up and erase, try the sequence BACKSPACE SPACE BACKSPACE.

This is the behavior of the DEC VT100 terminal, which is pretty ubiquitous (also called ANSI terminal, same is used by XTERM-derived terminals). As @jxh points out, adding terminal-specific sequences is only appropriate if the output device is a terminal. If you're writing to a file, this will not erase, but simply add these additional bytes to the output stream. However, these *delayed* sequences would still be interpreted correctly if written to the terminal at a later time, perhaps using `cat`. You could use the POSIX function `isatty(3)` to get a good guess at whether these sequences will be interpreted.

It may be possible to *unwrite* a character in a buffered write by adjusting the file position.

```
FILE *myfile = /*initialization*/;
/* ... */
fsetpos (myfile, -1, SEEK_CUR);
```

Please also consider MvG's valuable comments for more ways these methods may fail. (It really is shaky territory, being outside of the standard. brrrrr. :)

Comment: That would still leave invalid output if redirected to a file.

Comment: And if output were an old style printer, then the dash would be on paper, and no amount of moving the typing head back will make it vanish again. Some modern printers are designed to mimic the old ones. So some systems might represent this as a strike-through letter space. I don't argue, this is among the best that can be hoped for, but still not perfect. The `fsetpos` would fail if output happens to be an unbuffered tty. It will also leave the `-` in case no more data gets written.

Answer (score 4):

You could replace

```
digit2 = "\b";
```

by

```
if (digit1[0] != '\0')
    digit1[strlen(digit1) - 1] = '\0';
```

which effectively removes the trailing character from `digit1`.

Since this works completely on the level of your strings, you avoid relying on device-specific behaviour as `\b` would do.

Comment: Daggnabbit! Even your geometric gravatar is better than mine! Phooey. +1 for *fixing the problem* not the symptoms. :)

Answer (score 1):

The escape code "\b" emits a terminal-control character; that is, it writes an additional control character to the output stream, it does not remove previous characters from the output stream: On most systems "hellO\bo" produces a string literal of 8 bytes equivalent to `{ 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'O', '\b', 'o', '\0' };`

It is important, though, to remember that this is a terminal-control character. What it does is terminal dependent: some terminals move the cursor left stopping at column 0, some move the cursor left with wrap, some erase the character the cursor arrives at, others don't.

But further more, if you are viewing the data other than through a terminal, it is just a byte. E.g. the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    printf("Hello!\b\n");
}
```

will generate a sequence of ascii values that, if viewed with linux "cat" might display "Hello", with Windows/DOS "more" command, "Hello!" (DOS is a non-destructive backspace) and if loaded in notepad produce "Hello!" followed by what looks like a wing-ding.

Don't confuse terminal control with io-stream control.